# Create dynamic secret names in Github Actions

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

My goal is actually pretty easy but I am not sure if it is possible in the Github Actions or not. So I have an action file that is used for deployment of different Azure subscription/tenants. So I have different AZURE_CREDENTIALS for every one of them.

For example AZURE_CREDENTIALS_NUM1 is one of them. I am giving the name of NUM1 as a customer name to the script in a config file but I do not want to change everywhere in the script that use the same secret. I try this approach but it didn't work:

```
    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ "${{needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials}}" }}
```

Inside the needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials part, I created name for AZURE_CREDENTIALS_NUM1 but this syntax is not accepted by Github Actions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mask as below:

```yaml
    - name: Add mask
      run: |
        echo "::add-mask::${{needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials}}"
    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials}}
```

Then it will be masked in logs. For more details please check [here](https://www.tutorialworks.com/github-actions-mask-url/)

Comment: I think I explained it a bit fuzzy. The thing I am trying to achieve is a bit different. For example, Azure secret name will change every time I create a new deployment for different product. ${{needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials}} this output only holding the information of secret name. For examply the output is AZURE_CREDENTIALS_NUM1. in this example. I am trying to achieve dynamic secret name, so for example in the future deployment it will be AZURE_CREDENTIALS_NUM2

Answer (score 0):

when this step is running echo "::add-mask::${{needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials}}"
this value will be printed in the logs "${{needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials}}"
if ${{needs.Parameters.outputs.azureCredentials}}="password" in the logs it will show as below echo "::add-mask::password" indirectly we can see the creds in the logs!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).